# Iterate through vector<uchar> and count occurrence of values

Tags: c++

How to iterate through a `std::vector<uchar>` and count the occurrence of each value?

I'm still fairly new to C++ and don't really know the best approaches

My guess would be to iterate through the vector and register each occurrence in a new multidimensional vector

```
std::vector<uchar<int>> unique;
for(const auto& sample : quantized){
    // if unique[sample] does not exists create it and set the value to 1
    // if unique[sample] is set increase it by +1
}
```

And how would the logic look like in the above code? (if this is the best approach?)

I need to find the value with most occurrencies

Comment: Do you know data structure like map ?

Comment: You can use map or unordered_map to count frequency in c++. Here's a helpful link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-frequency-of-each-element-in-a-vector-using-map-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use an `unordered_map` as a counter by key.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  auto samples = // or from user input
      std::vector<int>{1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7,  8, 9, 10,
                       4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10};

  if (samples.size() == 0) {
    printf("No samples\n");
  }

  // counter, key is sample, value is count
  std::unordered_map<int, int> counter;

  // count samples
  for (auto sample : samples) {
    counter[sample]++;
  }

  // sort
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> sorted_counter;
  std::copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), std::back_inserter(sorted_counter));
  std::sort(sorted_counter.begin(), sorted_counter.end(),
            [](const std::pair<int, int> &a, const std::pair<int, int> &b) {
              // for asc, use a.second < b.second
              return a.second > b.second;
            });

  // print result
  for (auto &pair : sorted_counter) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", pair.first, pair.second);
  }
  
  printf("max freq sample: %d, count: %d\n", sorted_counter[0].first,
         sorted_counter[0].second);

  printf("min freq sample: %d, count: %d\n",
         sorted_counter[sorted_counter.size() - 1].first,
         sorted_counter[sorted_counter.size() - 1].second);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```cpp
1: 5
10: 3
9: 3
8: 2
6: 2
5: 2
4: 2
7: 1
max sample: 1, count: 5
min sample: 7, count: 1
```

The most freq item value is the first item of `desc_keys`.

Comment: Thanks :) What if I want to order it i asc mode? :)

Comment: Seems like your code is sorting by the key in the map. It should sort by the value in the map

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::map` to keep track of the occurrence of the values as shown below:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,34,2,44,34,243,5,2,1,554,6,3,7,9,54,643,6,3,2};

//create a mapping from each value to its occurence 
std::map<int, int> countOccurence; 

for(const int& element: vec)
{
    countOccurence[element]++; //increment the count corresponding to the current value and if the element is not present create it and set the count to corresponding count to 0 automatically
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/_IfCGVwM_)

Comment: Great! And how do I get the value with most occurrencies?

Comment: @clarkk You can use `std::max_element` for finding that out. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/RGM2MwPcV)